# CSS / JS to differentiate between tablet / ipad and smartphone?

Tags: javascript, android, css, tablet, smartphone

I have seen this thread

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

but it does not solve the question on how to determine, if the device is a tablet, or a smartphone.

ipod or ipad ok. But there are android devices for tablets and smartphones

Is there a way and if yes, how?

Comment: *"Is there a way?"* Yes, by parsing the useragent.

Comment: @KevinB I read in mentioned thread, that no, it does not seem to be a way to distinguish android smartphone and android tablet

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to adjust the layout based on the [viewport size](http://viewportsizes.com/) of the device.